# Can QGIS perform graphic clipping?

Tags: qgis, clip

In ArcGIS for Desktop there is an option to graphic clip inside the data frame - this clips the feature you're viewing without actually clipping the feature into a new feature.  Does Quantum GIS have a tool to do this?

Comment: Is this like a cosmetic clip that updates when you pan?

Comment: @NathanW 
No
Arc and Quantum both redraw when you pan though if that's what you mean?

Comment: No i mean what is the purpose of a `graphic clip`

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000000q000000.htm

Comment: Ok yes that is on the TODO list.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish virtually the same effect using the clipper.  Simply zoom to the extent you wish, select Clipping mode > Extent, and drag the cursor to the extent of the dataframe.

[image]